# before selecting a item from datalist it's move to another page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to select a city from a datalist then after selecting the city it should move to another page but it move to another page before i select any city. I am not able to figure out how to overcome this, any help will highly appreciable

My Html :

```
<label> SEARCH COUPONS </label>
  <input type="text" list="cityList" class="form-control" placeholder="Select City" ng-model="selectcity" ng-change="searcity(selectcity)" class="form-control">
       <datalist id="cityList">
           <option ng-repeat="city in cities.results" value="{{city.name}}">
       </datalist>
```

My Controller:

```
$scope.searcity = function (val) {
        var ciseurl = urlcs + val;
        $http.get(ciseurl, config).then(function (response) {
            $scope.cities = response.data;
            var x = $scope.cities.results;
            couponSvc.setCityId(x[length].id);
            $location.path("/couplist");
        });
        };
```

**i tried $timeout service :**

```
$scope.searcity = function (val) {
        var ciseurl = urlcs + val;
        $http.get(ciseurl, config).then(function (response) {
            $scope.cities = response.data;
            var x = $scope.cities.results;
            couponSvc.setCityId(x[length].id);

        });
        $timeout(callme, 3000);

        function callme(){
        $location.path("/couplist");
        console.log("Timeout occured, City Selected : " + val);    
        };
     };
```

but that have also some problem like
**first :** It set cityId of the first item from the datalist
**Second :** if user not enter anything within 3seconds it moves to another pages

Comment: check the console.It getting called during DOM initilization

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that 
`ng-change="searcity(selectcity)"` it's called immediately after it has been included in the DOM: much like a watcher (all watchers are called once after their creation).

To overcome this, try to set a simple if:

```
$scope.searcity = function (val) {
    if(val == null) //void the first initialization.
      return;
    var ciseurl = urlcs + val;
    $http.get(ciseurl, config).then(function (response) {
        $scope.cities = response.data;
        var x = $scope.cities.results;
        couponSvc.setCityId(x[length].id);
        $location.path("/couplist");
    });
};
```

Comment: as i typed in the input box it start searching for the city name with first character and selects the first city id

Comment: its because u added ngChange event

Comment: Exactly: on the change of your ng-model variable, you perform a $loaction.path. You should change your location only on selection, rigth?

Comment: yeah right @Luxor001 can you help me how to do that, i m newbie to angularjs

Comment: Well, i'm not sure i can fully understand your environment, but you can try to set ng-change in the option element, like this: <option ng-repeat="city in cities.results" value="{{city.name}}" ng-change="searchCity(city.name)"> and remove it from input text.

Answer (score 0):

Put check.This function is getting called during DOM initialization.

```
$scope.searcity = function (val) {

       if($scope.selectcity){
          var ciseurl = urlcs + val;
           $http.get(ciseurl, config).then(function (response) {
             $scope.cities = response.data;
             var x = $scope.cities.results;
             couponSvc.setCityId(x[length].id);
             $location.path("/couplist");
        });
      };
}
```

Comment: it sets first city id from the datalist before moving to another page